# how can I write text on an image in kivy app

Tags: kivy

how can I write text on an image in kivy app.I am showing the image  in kivy using image-widget.

Now I want to write text on the image (the same way we do in paint i.e user will click on the image and start writing text).

Answer (score 0):

your question is very broad. To answer you simply yes it is very much possible to do with kivy. The following example is a simple illustration you may work on it and make it your own.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

class Start(Screen):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Start()

MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
<Start>:
    Image:
        source: 'bg.png' #put your own image here
    TextInput:
        text: 'HELLO'
        foreground_color: 0,1,1,1
        font_size: 100
        bold: True
        size_hint: 1,0.5
        background_color: 0,0,0,0
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
```

Just to summarize; basically I am using a textinput with an invisible background. You can position the textinput according to where you want it in your image. There are functions you can also create to ensure that your image and textinput are always positioned in a particular way.

Please see more resources from [here](https://www.youtube.com/@CodeSliceTutorials).